# How to return two elements with same indexes from different tuples?

Tags: python

The task says that I have to create a function with an input string. Inside the function, I have two tuples. First - for names, second - for surnames if this string contains a name from the first tuple it has to return this name with a surname that has the same index.

That's what I did:

```
def find_full_name(text):
    if not text or type(text) != str:
        return text
names = ("Joe", "Scott", "John", "Stephen")
surnames = ("Warren", "Rixner", "Greiner", "Wong")
for name in names:
    if name in text:
        return name
```

My code only returns the name and I can't figure out how to return a surname too. I've been trying to compare indexes like names.index() == surnames.index() but I did not help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could find the index of the name in the names tuple:

```
ix = names.index(name)
```

Then you can index the other tuple with that index:

```
return (name, surnames[ix])
```

Alternatively (and more efficiently), you could change your loop to use an index in the first place:

```
for ix in range(len(names)):
    name = names[ix]
    if name in text:
        return (name, surnames[ix])
```

Comment: Or you can loop over `zip` like a Python coder would :-P. Or at least `enumerate`.

Comment: True, I have exposed myself as a non-native Python speaker!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Index method to retrieve a surname from the index of name tuple.

```
def find_full_name(text):
    names = ("Joe", "Scott", "John", "Stephen")
    surnames = ("Warren", "Rixner", "Greiner", "Wong")
    if not text or type(text) != str:
        return text
    else:
        for name in names:
            if name in text:
                return surnames[names.index(name)]
```